# How to check if application has been minimized or maximized by the user in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a Tkinter project in which I have to know whether the user has maximized the application or not. Is there any way to do this on Tkinter? If yes please advice.....

Comment: Use `root.winfo_ismapped()` where `root` is the root window.

Comment: Thank for answering but there is a problem. I looked for information about winfo_ismapped() but it says that it is used to check whether a widget is visible or not. I am talking about the whole window here..

Comment: Then use `root.state() == "zoomed"`.

Comment: Yes `root` is the whole window and calling it on `root` will check if it is visible or not

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, this one worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use events like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def unminimised(event):
    print("Unminimised")

def minimised(event):
    print("Minimised")

root.bind("<Map>", unminimised)
root.bind("<Unmap>", minimised)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this but I wanted to know if there was anyway I could know if the window is **maximized** or not. By "maximized" I mean if the window is small or enlarged to the whole screen

Comment: @Coder You mean full-screen or not?

Comment: The middle one of the three on the top-right corner of your computer window (Windows). Your code only works for the one on the left, the '-' one.

Comment: Well for that you have to use what @acw1668 suggested `root.state() == "zoomed"`.

Comment: I think we got confused between minimised (the window isn't visible), maximised (the window takes up the whole screen but still has the toolbar - the one with the "_" and "X") and full screen (takes up the whole window but there is no toolbar)

Comment: Yes you are right. Anyways thanks for responding quickly :)